# Cannot correctly print extended ASCII characters in NCURSES

Tags: c, ascii, ncurses

I have this program:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main () {
    initscr();
    mvaddstr(0, 0, "              A         B         C         D         E       ");
    mvaddstr(1, 24, "ñandñ");
    mvaddstr(1, 34, "esdrñjulñ");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

When ncurses prints the first word (ñandñ) something happens that when moving to another position afterwards (in this case to 1, 34), actually it moves to another position, so the second word gets printed in another column.

So what it should look like:

```
          A         B         C         D         E       
                              ñandñ     esdrñjulñ
```

looks like this:

```
          A         B         C         D         E       
                              ñandñ   esdrñjulñ
```

because of the two 'ñ' extended ascii char in the first word.

Any idea what is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What platform are you using? Did you compile with `-Wall` and then *fix all the warnings*?

Comment: Does your sourcefile have the encoding that ncurses in your environment expects?

Comment: I did compile with -Wall and there was no output. No warning. Nothing.

Comment: FIle has "UTF-8 Unicode C program text" encoding. How do I know what is the encoding ncurses expects?

Comment: There's a ncurses version for wide character treatement.  You'll need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use multibyte UTF-8 characters, you must use the version of the ncurses library compiled with multibyte support, and you need to set the locale correctly at the beginning of your program.

The multibyte ncurses library is usually called `libncursesw`, so to use it is is sufficient to change `-lncurses` to `-lncursesw` in your linker options. You do not need a different header file. However, if you actually want to use the wide-character functions, you must `#define` the symbol `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` before any `#include` directive. The easiest way to do that with gcc (or clang) is to add `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` to your compiler options.

If your shell's locale has been set to a UTF-8 locale (which will usually be the case on a modern Linux distribution), it is sufficient to insert

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

before any call to an ncurses routine. That sets the executable's locale to the locale configured by the environment variables. You'll need to add

```
#include <locale.h>
```

to your header includes. No special library needs to be linked for locale support.

---

The original question indicated that `mvaddwstr` was being used. That's generally a better solution for multibyte characters, but as indicated above, you can use the narrow string interfaces if you want to. However, you cannot output incomplete UTF-8 sequences, so the single-character narrow interfaces like `addch` can only be used with character codes less than 128.

This note applied to an attempt to call `mvaddwstr` with a `char*` instead of a `wchar_t*` argument. Don't do that:

Like all of the `w` ncurses functions which accept strings, `mvaddwstr` takes a `wchar_t*` as its string argument. Your compiler should have warned you about that (unless it warned you that there was no prototype for `mvaddwstr`). So the strings should be prefixed with the `L` length attribute: `L"ñandñ"`.

Comment: As I said before my program has mvaddstr and not mvaddwstr calls.
I wrote those wrong. Just edit the post and correct it.
I am using ncurses lib rather than ncursesw and when i run gcc file.c -lncurses -Wall , I get no warning.

Comment: @andres: you still need the setlocale call and you need to link with `-lncursesw` instead of `-lncurses`. Then it should work.

Comment: It worked with -lncursesw and setting locale!!
Now, is it a must to use -lncursesw rather than -lncurses if I use mvaddstr ??

Comment: @Andres: It is a must if you want UTF-8 sequences to be handled correctly, regardless of whether you output them with wide or narrow ncurses functions. I'll edit the answer since you've edited the question.

Comment: Since I only want to handle extended ascii in my program, can I use ISO 8859-1 encoding, and link to -lncurses then?

Comment: @Andres: Sure. But your entire environment is probably set up for UTF-8. So you'll need to change your locale, the encoding being used by your terminal programs, and lots more. I guarantee you that it's more work than just adding a single character to your linker command.